# テキストファイル内の文字列を、辞書内のキーから検索し、バリューの要素数をだしたい。

Tags: python

初心者のため、おかしな点があるかもしれませんがよろしくお願いします。

テキストファイルの中身

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

```
辞書 = {
  'AAA':['a','b','c'],
  'BBB':['a','b','d','g'],
  'CCC':['b','f'],
  'DDD':['b','c','f','g','h']
}
```

テキストファイルも辞書も簡易化してます。

求める結果はキー毎の要素数です。

```
3
4
2
5
```

私は知識がないため以下のようなスクリプトを書きました。しかし、手作業で指定しないといけないため、汎用性がないと感じ質問しました。
よろしくお願いします。

```
バリュー = 辞書.get('AAA')
print(len(バリュー))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
dic = {'AAA':['a','b','c'],'BBB':['a','b','d','g'],'CCC':['b','f'],'DDD':['b','c','f','g','h']}
with open('keys.txt', 'r') as f:
    for key in f:
        value = dic.get(key.rstrip(), None)
        if value is not None:
            print(len(value))
        
# 3
# 4
# 2
# 5
```

Answer (score 1):

以下のように試してみてください。

```
for key in 辞書.keys():
    print(len(辞書[key]))
```